# Finding coordinates that diagonalize the metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces

I'm reading a solved problem which states that we have a bidimensional metric space whose metric is
$$
ds^2 = dv^2 - v^2 du^2
$$
and we want to find a coordinate transformation such that we get the Minkowski's bidimensional metric space
$$
ds^2 = dx^2 - dt^2\ .
$$

The solution involves equating both metrics,
$$
dv^2 - v^2 du^2 = dx^2 - dt^2\ .
$$
Then, for $x = x(u, v)$ and $t = t(u, v)$ we have
$$
dx = \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} du + \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} dv \quad\text{and}\quad dt = \dfrac{\partial t}{\partial u} du + \dfrac{\partial t}{\partial v} dv\ .
$$
Substituting these expressions in the equality of the metrics, we arrive at a system of partial differential equations.

The solution keeps going stating that we can solve the system with the method of variable separation,
$$
x(u, v) = U(u) V(v) \quad\text{and}\quad t(u, v) = T(u)S(v)\ ,
$$
leading to the system
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l} U'^2 V^2 - T'^2 S^2 = -v^2 \\ V'^2 U^2 - S'^2 T^2 = 1 \\ UU' VV' = TT'SS' \end{array} \right.
$$

I understand the following step, which is realizing from the third equation that
$$
\dfrac{UU'}{TT'} = \dfrac{SS'}{VV'} = \text{constant}\ ,
$$
but suddenly the proposed solution is like "from this we instantly get"
$$
x(u,v) = v \cosh u \quad\text{y}\quad t(u,v) = v \sinh u\ .
$$

I wonder if someone could give a more detailed step by step solution for this system of differential equations, or any hint about how to proceed. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This works in suitable quadrants of the plane. Let's focus on the region $v>0$. The relations $$x = v\cosh u\quad\mbox{and}\quad t = v\sinh u$$are what you need. We have that $${\rm d}x = \cosh u\,{\rm d}v + v\sinh u\,{\rm d}u\quad\mbox{and}\quad {\rm d}t = \sinh u\,{\rm d}v+v\cosh u\,{\rm d}u,$$so $$\begin{align} {\rm d}x^2-{\rm d}t^2&= \cosh^2u\,{\rm d}v^2 + v\sinh(2u)\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v+v^2\sinh^2u\,{\rm d}u^2 \\ & \quad - \sinh^2u\,{\rm d}v^2 - v\sinh(2u)\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v - v^2\cosh^2u\,{\rm d}u^2 \\  &= {\rm d}v^2 - v^2\,{\rm d}u^2,\end{align}$$by using that $\cosh^2u-\sinh^2u = 1$. The coordinates $(u,v)$ are called *Rindler coordinates* in the Minkowski plane. It's the Lorentz analogue of polar coordinates, where ${\rm d}x^2+{\rm d}y^2 = {\rm d}r^2+r^2\,{\rm d}\theta^2$.